# How to disable SHA1 in Signature Algorithm TLS extension in client hello message?

Tags: tls, openssl

In TLS1.2, There is TLS extension: signature_algorithm,

[image]

As SHA1 is not recommended, so I want to disable the SHA1 hash algorithm.
I used OpenSSL API to set signature algorithm to SSL_CTX,

```
  /* signature algorithm list */
  const char signAlgo[] = "NID_sha256, EVP_PKEY_RSA";
  (void)SSL_CTX_set1_client_sigalgs(ctx, signAlgo, 2);
```

but, still SHA1 is not disabled. It is showing all the algorithms.
Can anyone suggest me, is there any other way to disable the SHA1 in TLS Extension: signature_algorithm client hello message.

Comment: Probably you need to read https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html, you will find the answer to your question of how to disable/enable specific algorithms, the openssl have that functionality all ready.

Comment: Thanks but I am developing my client application, I am not using the openssl binaries

Comment: I consider this a pure programming question, i.e. off-topic. But I recommend to actually have a look [at the documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_CTX_set1_client_sigalgs.html) and also enable compiler warnings  - then you will hopefully realize that the `signAlgo` argument you use should not be a `char[]` as you do but  an `int[]` containing NID. For a string as argument have a look at `SSL_CTX_set1_sigalgs_list` instead but note the documented syntax you have to use which is different from your attempts.